# Is it possible to avoid .scala.html suffix in playframework?

Tags: html, scala, templates, playframework, scala-template

I hate long filename, and scala here make no sense to me(I don't use scala at all). So is there any way to remove `.scala` suffix ?

Comment: Off topic: believe me that there are many systems with muuuuch longer namespaces, Play is brilliant in this topic :) if it's so annoying for you just create some shortcut in your IDE, and that's all

Answer (score 1):

**No,not Possible I Think!** neither for `html` or `xml`

you need to use `.scala.html`
or `.Scala.xml`

**Templates** are compiled as standard Scala functions in **Play Framework**.

If you create a `views/Application/index.scala.html` template file, it will generate a `views.html.Application.index` class that has an `apply()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense as you mix Scala code (@...) with html in such file. Btw template file is compiled to be a scala function you can call from other scala code.